# Jquery issues for Expand/Collapse table

Tags: jquery, datagrid

I have developed a jquery based expand/collapse table with an option of creating new sets of same expand/collapse feature also with deleting.

1. Exp/collpse is not working for the news ones

   UPDATE: Fixed the exp/collapse issue. I need to generate Ids for new created TR's. How can i do that..?

Can anyone please help me. Here is the implementation.
http://jsfiddle.net/pixelfx/wJBgt/14/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**2.**

```
$('.delete').live('click', function() {
   $("#something").find("tr:gt(1)").remove();
   return false;
});
```

So you click delete on anything and what do you do? You find all rows greater then 1. So any row in the table that is not the first row and you delete it. It's doing exactly what you asked for.

Try `$(this).closest("tr").remove()` instead.

**1.**

```
$(function() {
    $('tr.parent').css("cursor", "pointer").attr("title", "Click to expand/collapse").click(function() {
        $(this).siblings('.child-' + this.id).toggle();
    });
    $('tr[class^=child-]').hide().children('td');
});
```

your click for the new ones doesn't work because you didn't use `.live`. and only attaches to the current row rather then all rows.

There are a lot more things wrong with the code based on design decisions, I can't really make it work as "intended" without redoing the entire thing.

Some-one else can do that for you ;)

Comment: i want to del the specific row which i click. But now all the rows are getting deleted once i click del

Comment: @nahom remove the closest tr. And write your own code to remove the `.child-...` ones

Comment: i am new to jquery, trying wt ever i can